# Community Promotion Ads

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

One great way to promote a site is through Community Promotion Ads on graduated Stack Exchange Sites.

Here is part of the canonical spiel given on meta posts on graduated sites where we submit our ads for voting (six upvotes and our ad is shown on the site), repurposed for a different use:

> #### What are Community Promotion Ads?
>
> Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.
>
> #### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
>
> This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:
>
> - the site's twitter account
> - useful tools or resources for physics research
> - interesting articles or findings for the curious
> - cool events or conferences
> - anything else your community would genuinely be interested in
>
> The goal is for future visitors to find out about the stuff your community deems important. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are relevant to your own community's interests, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.
>
> #### Why do we reset the ads every year?
>
> Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.
>
> The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.
>
> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

For more information, see [What's the best way to create a community ad for a beta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247037/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-community-ad-for-a-beta-site)

So please, go out and create ads or suggest ideas for ads for Lifehacks. Submit them here with the image of the ad you've made and what site it should go on.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of image we should build. No color builds the theme of macgyver'ing nor does any photo compose the idea of our site.